# Set PSTN number is GotoMeeting

Tags: asp.net, openmeetings

I am new to the GotoMeeting API and find the solution for creating a meeting over to the goto meeting, if we set the conferencing info as PSTN means according to the country.

Like i want to fetch the toll free number for a particular country. On the documentation they have implemented the Hybrid part.

So unable to find the solution for PSTN only. I may using below code for hybrid :-

```
    string url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2M/rest/meetings";
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";       
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_token=" + txt_AccessCode.Text);

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();        
    DateTime endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(30.0);
    Hashtable postObj = new Hashtable();

    postObj["subject"] = MeetingName;
    postObj["starttime"] = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    postObj["endtime"] = endTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    postObj["passwordrequired"] = "true";
    postObj["conferencecallinfo"] = "Hybrid";
    postObj["timezonekey"] = "65";
    postObj["meetingtype"] = "Scheduled";

    String s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postObj);
    String result = "";
    var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
```

Please help me in converting this code for retrieving to PSTN number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the PSTN country code in the request for GoToMeeting. We have to set the same in settings -> conference Information in our gotomeeting accounts. So when we pass the request as PSTN then it will retrieve only those country which are specified in the settings area.